# Получить доступ к началу второй строки в TextView

Tags: java, android, строки

Есть String, который в TextView автоматически переносит слова на вторую строку из-за большое количества слов в одной строке. Хотела бы получить доступ к началу второй строки для последующего редактирования.

Пыталась проверять на "\n", но это не сработало.

Какие могут быть варианты решения?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы поймать начало второй строки вам нужно отлавливать конец первой, для этого советую использовать `getLineEnd(int line)` и вы будете перемещаться к началу второй строки. Но я бы вам советовал использовать все-таки для решения вашей задачи такой вью элемент как `editText` так как свойства редактирования textView несколько ограниченны и не дадут вам свободу выбора. Для того чтобы найти начало второй строки в editText вам нужно использовать такую конструкцию:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher(){
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged( CharSequence txt, int start, int before, int count ) {
    if( -1 != txt.toString().indexOf("\n") ){
      //ваше действие
    }
  }
} );
```

editText более удобен для отслеживания изменений текста и в нем будет проще его редактировать. Для того чтобы установить текст в поле для ввода вам поможет:

```
editText.setText("some_text", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

так же у него есть такая же функция установки текста как и у textView:

```
editText.setText("Hello world!");
editText.setText(R.string.hello_world);
```

[документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html) связанная с textView.